# Jquery enhancement code for showing progress bar properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the jquery code which works well but there is an issue that jquery xhr request completes and it loads the data lot later, i want the progress bar to be at least 99% accurate but it gets completed soon and the data is loaded too late

how can i add text inside it, like percentage and if its reaches 98%, the text will change to `almost done` and `loading results` and `lastly sit tight, we are showing results`

how can i do that

here is my JS Code and html Code

```
$("#btnUsers").click(function() {
    var form = $("#users");
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('data-action'),
        async: true,
        type: form.attr('data-method'),
        data: $("#users").serialize(),
        xhr: function () {
          $("#TrendingResultsNoShow").hide();
          $("#TrendingResults").hide();    
          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Upload Progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100; $('div.progress > div.progress-bar').css({ "width": percentComplete + "%" }); } }, false);
            //Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
         if (evt.lengthComputable){ 
            var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) *100;
                $("div.progress > div.progress-bar").css({ "width": percentComplete + "%" }); 
            } 
        },false);
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#TrendingResultsNoShow").hide();
            $('.progress-bar').animate({width: "100%"}, 100);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.progress-bar').css({width: "100%"});
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#TrendingResults').html(data);
                }, 100);
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});
```

HTMl Code

```
<div id="TrendingResultsNoShow">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card-box" align="center">
        <img src="images/hashtag.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="TrendingResults" class="row"></div>
<div class="progress"> <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;height:30px;"></div> </div>
```

Comment: Please read the first paragraph on **Attributes** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div#attributes

Comment: what is wrong here